# source() taking long time and often crashed

Tags: r

I used `dump()` command to dump some dataframes in R. 
The particular dump files are about 200 MB, and one is about1.5 GB. Later I tried to retrieve them using `source()` and it is taking a lot of time and says windows stopped working after 3-4 hours. I am using 64 bit  R 3.0.0 ( I tried in R 2.15.3 too) in windows 7 with memory of 48 GB. For one of the file, It threw some memory error, (I don't have log now) but loaded 4-5 datasets out of about 15 datasets.

Is there any way I can load a particular dataset if I know name? 
or is there any other way?

I have learned my lesson and probably save command to create data and the original data. or one data in one dump file (or R image file)

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `save()` and `load()` rather than `dump()` and `source()`.

`save()` writes out an binary representation of the data to an `.Rdata` file, which can then be loaded back in using `load()`.

`dump()` converts everything to a text representation, which `source()` then has to reconvert back to binary. Both ends of that process are *very* inefficient.

Comment: Josh,Yes thats what I learned from this I will use save.image() or save() from now on